# Cube with two textures

Tags: webgl, textures, cube

```js
/**
 * A class creating buffers for a textured box to render it with WebGL
 */
class RasterTextureBox {
    /**
     * Creates all WebGL buffers for the textured box
     *     6 ------- 7
     *    / |       / |
     *   3 ------- 2  |
     *   |  |      |  |
     *   |  5 -----|- 4
     *   | /       | /
     *   0 ------- 1
     *  looking in negative z axis direction
     * @param {WebGLContext} gl - The canvas' context
     * @param {Vector} minPoint - The minimal x,y,z of the box
     * @param {Vector} maxPoint - The maximal x,y,z of the box
     */
    constructor(gl, minPoint, maxPoint, texture) {
        this.gl = gl;
        const mi = minPoint;
        const ma = maxPoint;
        let vertices = [
            // front
            mi.x, mi.y, ma.z, ma.x, mi.y, ma.z, ma.x, ma.y, ma.z,
            ma.x, ma.y, ma.z, mi.x, ma.y, ma.z, mi.x, mi.y, ma.z,
            // back
            ma.x, mi.y, mi.z, mi.x, mi.y, mi.z, mi.x, ma.y, mi.z,
            mi.x, ma.y, mi.z, ma.x, ma.y, mi.z, ma.x, mi.y, mi.z,
            // right
            ma.x, mi.y, ma.z, ma.x, mi.y, mi.z, ma.x, ma.y, mi.z,
            ma.x, ma.y, mi.z, ma.x, ma.y, ma.z, ma.x, mi.y, ma.z,
            // top
            mi.x, ma.y, ma.z, ma.x, ma.y, ma.z, ma.x, ma.y, mi.z,
            ma.x, ma.y, mi.z, mi.x, ma.y, mi.z, mi.x, ma.y, ma.z,
            // left
            mi.x, mi.y, mi.z, mi.x, mi.y, ma.z, mi.x, ma.y, ma.z,
            mi.x, ma.y, ma.z, mi.x, ma.y, mi.z, mi.x, mi.y, mi.z,
            // bottom
            mi.x, mi.y, mi.z, ma.x, mi.y, mi.z, ma.x, mi.y, ma.z,
            ma.x, mi.y, ma.z, mi.x, mi.y, ma.z, mi.x, mi.y, mi.z
        ];

        const vertexBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);
        gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(vertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
        this.vertexBuffer = vertexBuffer;
        this.elements = vertices.length / 3;

        let cubeTexture = gl.createTexture();
        let cubeImage = new Image();
        cubeImage.onload = function () {
            gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, cubeTexture);
            gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, cubeImage);
            gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
            gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
            gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
            gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, null);
        }
        cubeImage.src = texture;
        this.texBuffer = cubeTexture;

        let uv = [
            // front
            0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1,
            1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0,
            // back
            0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1,
            1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0,
            // right
            0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1,
            1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0,
            // top
            0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1,
            1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0,
            // left
            0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1,
            1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0,
            // bottom
            0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1,
            1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0,
        ];
        let uvBuffer = this.gl.createBuffer();
        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, uvBuffer);
        gl.bufferData(this.gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(uv),
            gl.STATIC_DRAW);
        this.texCoords = uvBuffer;
    }

    /**
     * Renders the textured box
     * @param {Shader} shader - The shader used to render
     */
    render(shader) {
        this.gl.bindBuffer(this.gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this.vertexBuffer);
        const positionLocation = shader.getAttributeLocation("a_position");
        this.gl.enableVertexAttribArray(positionLocation);
        this.gl.vertexAttribPointer(positionLocation, 3, this.gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

        // Bind the texture coordinates in this.texCoords
        // to their attribute in the shader
        // TODO [exercise 9]
        this.gl.bindBuffer(this.gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this.texCoords);
        const texCoordLocation = shader.getAttributeLocation("a_texCoord");
        this.gl.enableVertexAttribArray(texCoordLocation);
        this.gl.vertexAttribPointer(texCoordLocation, 2, this.gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

        this.gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0);
        this.gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, this.texBuffer);
        shader.getUniformInt("sampler").set(0);
        this.gl.drawArrays(this.gl.TRIANGLES, 0, this.elements);

        this.gl.disableVertexAttribArray(positionLocation);

        // TODO [exercise 9] disable texture vertex attrib array
        this.gl.disableVertexAttribArray(texCoordLocation);
    }
}
```

```html
<script id="2d-fragment-shader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
precision mediump float;

uniform sampler2D sampler;
varying vec2 v_texCoord;

void main( void ) {
  //gl_FragColor = vec4( 0.0, 0.0, 0.5, 1.0 );
  // Read fragment color from texture
  // TODO [exercise 9]
  gl_FragColor = texture2D(sampler, vec2(v_texCoord.s, v_texCoord.t));
}
</script>

<script id="2d-vertex-shader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
attribute vec3 a_position;
attribute vec2 a_texCoord;
varying vec2 v_texCoord;

uniform mat4 M;
uniform mat4 V;
uniform mat4 P;

void main(void)
{
    gl_Position = P * V * M * vec4( a_position, 1.0 );
    v_texCoord = a_texCoord;
}
```

Hey there, I`m trying tp add two textures on my cube (code on top). I can combine two images two one, but I have no idea how to combine my cube with the two images. My cube already has one texture, I just want to add another one via constructor. Looking forward for your help! I´m thankful for every advice or code examples!

```html
<!-- Licensed under a BSD license. See license.html for license -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes">
    <title>WebGL - 2 Textures</title>
    <link type="text/css" href="webgl-tutorials.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
</body>
<!-- vertex shader -->
<script id="2d-vertex-shader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
attribute vec2 a_position;
attribute vec2 a_texCoord;

uniform vec2 u_resolution;

varying vec2 v_texCoord;

void main() {
   // convert the rectangle from pixels to 0.0 to 1.0
   vec2 zeroToOne = a_position / u_resolution;

   // convert from 0->1 to 0->2
   vec2 zeroToTwo = zeroToOne * 2.0;

   // convert from 0->2 to -1->+1 (clipspace)
   vec2 clipSpace = zeroToTwo - 1.0;

   gl_Position = vec4(clipSpace * vec2(1, -1), 0, 1);

   // pass the texCoord to the fragment shader
   // The GPU will interpolate this value between points.
   v_texCoord = a_texCoord;
}
</script>
<!-- fragment shader -->
<script id="2d-fragment-shader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
precision mediump float;

// our textures
uniform sampler2D u_image0;
uniform sampler2D u_image1;

// the texCoords passed in from the vertex shader.
varying vec2 v_texCoord;

void main() {
   vec4 color0 = texture2D(u_image0, v_texCoord);
   vec4 color1 = texture2D(u_image1, v_texCoord);
   gl_FragColor = color0 * color1;
}
</script>
<!--
for most samples webgl-utils only provides shader compiling/linking and
canvas resizing because why clutter the examples with code that's the same in every sample.
See http://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-boilerplate.html
and http://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-resizing-the-canvas.html
for webgl-utils, m3, m4, and webgl-lessons-ui.
-->
<script src="https://webgl2fundamentals.org/webgl/resources/webgl-utils.js"></script>
<script>
    "use strict";

    function loadImage(url, callback) {
        var image = new Image();
        image.src = url;
        image.onload = callback;
        return image;
    }

    function loadImages(urls, callback) {
        var images = [];
        var imagesToLoad = urls.length;

        // Called each time an image finished
        // loading.
        var onImageLoad = function() {
            --imagesToLoad;
            // If all the images are loaded call the callback.
            if (imagesToLoad == 0) {
                callback(images);
            }
        };

        for (var ii = 0; ii < imagesToLoad; ++ii) {
            var image = loadImage(urls[ii], onImageLoad);
            images.push(image);
        }
    }

    function main() {
        loadImages([
            "star.jpg",
            "normal.png",
        ], render);
    }

    function render(images) {
        // Get A WebGL context
        /** @type {HTMLCanvasElement} */
        var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
        var gl = canvas.getContext("webgl");
        if (!gl) {
            return;
        }

        // setup GLSL program
        var program = webglUtils.createProgramFromScripts(gl, ["2d-vertex-shader", "2d-fragment-shader"]);
        gl.useProgram(program);

        // look up where the vertex data needs to go.
        var positionLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "a_position");
        var texcoordLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "a_texCoord");

        // Create a buffer to put three 2d clip space points in
        var positionBuffer = gl.createBuffer();

        // Bind it to ARRAY_BUFFER (think of it as ARRAY_BUFFER = positionBuffer)
        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer);
        // Set a rectangle the same size as the image.
        setRectangle(gl, 0, 0, images[0].width, images[0].height);

        // provide texture coordinates for the rectangle.
        var texcoordBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, texcoordBuffer);
        gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array([
            0.0,  0.0,
            1.0,  0.0,
            0.0,  1.0,
            0.0,  1.0,
            1.0,  0.0,
            1.0,  1.0,
        ]), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

        // create 2 textures
        var textures = [];
        for (var ii = 0; ii < 2; ++ii) {
            var texture = gl.createTexture();
            gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);

            // Set the parameters so we can render any size image.
            gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
            gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
            gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
            gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);

            // Upload the image into the texture.
            gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, images[ii]);

            // add the texture to the array of textures.
            textures.push(texture);
        }

        // lookup uniforms
        var resolutionLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "u_resolution");

        // lookup the sampler locations.
        var u_image0Location = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "u_image0");
        var u_image1Location = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "u_image1");

        webglUtils.resizeCanvasToDisplaySize(gl.canvas);

        gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);

        // Clear the canvas
        gl.clearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
        gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        // Tell it to use our program (pair of shaders)
        gl.useProgram(program);

        // Turn on the position attribute
        gl.enableVertexAttribArray(positionLocation);

        // Bind the position buffer.
        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer);

        // Tell the position attribute how to get data out of positionBuffer (ARRAY_BUFFER)
        var size = 2;          // 2 components per iteration
        var type = gl.FLOAT;   // the data is 32bit floats
        var normalize = false; // don't normalize the data
        var stride = 0;        // 0 = move forward size * sizeof(type) each iteration to get the next position
        var offset = 0;        // start at the beginning of the buffer
        gl.vertexAttribPointer(
            positionLocation, size, type, normalize, stride, offset)

        // Turn on the teccord attribute
        gl.enableVertexAttribArray(texcoordLocation);

        // Bind the position buffer.
        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, texcoordBuffer);

        // Tell the position attribute how to get data out of positionBuffer (ARRAY_BUFFER)
        var size = 2;          // 2 components per iteration
        var type = gl.FLOAT;   // the data is 32bit floats
        var normalize = false; // don't normalize the data
        var stride = 0;        // 0 = move forward size * sizeof(type) each iteration to get the next position
        var offset = 0;        // start at the beginning of the buffer
        gl.vertexAttribPointer(
            texcoordLocation, size, type, normalize, stride, offset)

        // set the resolution
        gl.uniform2f(resolutionLocation, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);

        // set which texture units to render with.
        gl.uniform1i(u_image0Location, 0);  // texture unit 0
        gl.uniform1i(u_image1Location, 1);  // texture unit 1

        // Set each texture unit to use a particular texture.
        gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0);
        gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);
        gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE1);
        gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, textures[1]);

        // Draw the rectangle.
        gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
    }

    function setRectangle(gl, x, y, width, height) {
        var x1 = x;
        var x2 = x + width;
        var y1 = y;
        var y2 = y + height;
        gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array([
            x1, y1,
            x2, y1,
            x1, y2,
            x1, y2,
            x2, y1,
            x2, y2,
        ]), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
    }

    main();
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean "add 2 textures on my cube"? how do you want to add them? Do you want different textures on different faces? Do you want the two images to be blended over each other one each face? Do you want 2 images display independently? Scaled? Rotated? Repeated? [This article shows 6 images on a cube](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-3d-textures.html)

Comment: Every face of the cube should show the same, but with the two images kinda blendend over each other. Like this: https://webgl2fundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-2-textures.html The cube is rotating, but doesn´t have to move at first. I just want to add the faces to the cube.

Comment: Can you post an [MCVE](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/349790/128511) in a [snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your code works you need to change your fragment shader to use two textures

```
<script id="2d-fragment-shader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
precision mediump float;

uniform sampler2D sampler1;
uniform sampler2D sampler2;
varying vec2 v_texCoord;

void main( void ) {
  //gl_FragColor = vec4( 0.0, 0.0, 0.5, 1.0 );
  // Read fragment color from texture
  // TODO [exercise 9]
  gl_FragColor = texture2D(sampler1, vec2(v_texCoord.s, v_texCoord.t)) *
                 texture2D(sampler2, vec2(v_texCoord.s, v_texCoord.t));
}
</script>
```

And you need to make your JavaScript load 2 textures

```
 * @param {strings[]} textures An array of urls for textures
 */
constructor(gl, minPoint, maxPoint, textures) {

    this.texBuffers = textures.map((texture) => {
      const cubeTexture = gl.createTexture();
      const cubeImage = new Image();
      cubeImage.onload = function () {
        gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, cubeTexture);
        gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, cubeImage);
        gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
        gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, null);
      }
      cubeImage.src = texture;
      return cubeTexture;
    });
```

Then in your render code you need to set both textures

```
    this.texBuffers.forEach((texBuffer, ndx) => {
      this.gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0 + ndx);
      this.gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texBuffer);
      shader.getUniformInt(`sampler${ndx}`).set(ndx);
    });
```

And you'd call your constructor like this

```
const rtBox = new RasterTextureBox(gl, minPoint, maxPoint, [
  "some/url/to/image1.png",
  "some/url/to/image2.png",
]);
```